# How can I set doInbackground finish its task before continuing the mainActivity?

Tags: java, android, html, mysql, android-studio

***These are my `MainActivity`:***

```java
    database_connector wp_terms = new database_connector("SELECT * FROM  `dse120071750`.`wp_terms` ",progressDialog,this);
    wp_terms.execute();
    wp_terms.onPreExecute();
    try {

        for (int i=0; i<wp_terms.getJsonArray().length(); i++){
            JSONObject obj = wp_terms.getJsonArray().getJSONObject(i);
            this.wp_terms.put(obj.getString("term_id"), obj.getString("name"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

***DatabaseConnector:***

```
package hk.hoome.www.mobilehoome;

public class database_connector extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, Void> {

//String mode;
HttpResponse response;
String sql;
JSONArray jsonArray;
searchPage searchPage;

public database_connector(String sql, searchPage searchPage){
    //this.mode = mode;
    this.sql = sql;
    this.searchPage = searchPage;
    jsonArray = new JSONArray();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    connect();
    publishProgress();
    return null;
}



@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

}

public void connect() {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sql", sql));
    //nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mode", mode));
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.hoome.hk/hoomeMobileApps/connectDB.php");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, "UTF-8"));
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity  = response.getEntity();
        String entityResponse  = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        Log.e("Entity Response ", entityResponse.substring(2));
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse.substring(2));

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public JSONArray getJsonArray(){
    return jsonArray;
}
```

}

When I ran this code, `for (int i=0; i<wp_terms.getJsonArray().length(); i++){` this results in a `nullPointerException`.

I believe that this is because `doInbackground` hasn't finished its process but `mainActivity` keeps running. How can I set that `doInbackground` has to be done before continue running the mainActivity?

**SOLUTION?**

```
   try {
        while (wp_posts.getJsonArray().equals(null))
            Thread.sleep(1000);                 
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
```

is this a good solution?

Comment: Could you add the language and platform as tags to the question?

Comment: You have to use onPostExecute callback for after completion of background task scenarios. Read AsyncTask documentation in developer site.

Comment: If this were Swift, I would have a function to parse and store the JSON, and then I would only call that function in the completion block of the network request.  Does Java have that same kind of functionality?

Comment: @Harish Sridharan Probably, I don't quite understand how Asynctask operates. The documentation mentions that onPostExecute is run after doInBackground is completed. However, doInbackground is finished after the mainActivity is finished. How can I prioritize doInbackground, or the Asynctask, before mainActivity. (I hope this question can show how I don't understand Asynctask....)

Comment: @PyNewb No, in Java you cannot call functions at all. We only have variables, but they are so expensive that most programmers cannot afford them. Most of us are forced to code exclusively using semicolons.

Comment: @ykn121 can you post the full code of MainActivity and database_connector class? I will help you and explain how a AsyncTask works. Your possible solution is not a good solution. In fact a worst one. You should never call Thread.sleep() on main thread.

Comment: @Harish Sridharan I edited my post. For `mainActivity`, it is a bit messy. I hope the code of `databaseconnector` is enough to show what I want to do.

Comment: @ykn121 added my answer. Check out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a callback in your database connector class and pass the completion callback. For the simplicity I'm using Runnable interface. In general, try to have your own interface and also to pass the params between the background thread and the main thread over your custom interface.

```
package hk.hoome.www.mobilehoome;

public class database_connector extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, Void> {

//String mode;
HttpResponse response;
String sql;
JSONArray jsonArray;
searchPage searchPage;
private Runnable activityCallback;

public void setCallback(Runnable callback) {
    this.activityCallback = callback;
}

public database_connector(String sql, searchPage searchPage){
    //this.mode = mode;
    this.sql = sql;
    this.searchPage = searchPage;
    jsonArray = new JSONArray();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    connect();
    publishProgress();
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    if(activityCallback != null) {
        activityCallback.run();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

}

public void connect() {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sql", sql));
    //nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mode", mode));
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.hoome.hk/hoomeMobileApps/connectDB.php");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, "UTF-8"));
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity  = response.getEntity();
        String entityResponse  = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        Log.e("Entity Response ", entityResponse.substring(2));
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse.substring(2));

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public JSONArray getJsonArray(){
    return jsonArray;
}
}
```

In your MainActivity

```
database_connector wp_terms = new database_connector("SELECT * FROM  `dse120071750`.`wp_terms` ",progressDialog,this);
wp_terms.setCallback(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

        try {

                for (int i=0; i<wp_terms.getJsonArray().length(); i++){
                    JSONObject obj = wp_terms.getJsonArray().getJSONObject(i);
                    this.wp_terms.put(obj.getString("term_id"),      obj.getString("name"));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    wp_terms.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! You solved my problem but may I know what is the working principle?

Comment: Thanks :) The simplest principle, after doInBackground() is completed in background thread, it will automatically call onPostExecute() on main thread. Here were have provided an interface to redirect the completion call and perform the JSON fetching.

PS: Since it worked, please accept the answer and also upvote if you hav'nt

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem in one of my project, this is what might help you

```
public class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(String...params) {
     String result;
     //background tasks here.
     return result;
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       //task after doInBackground here.

 }
 }
```

doInBackground():
Override this method to perform a computation on a background thread.

```
onPostExecute():

Runs on the UI thread after doInBackground(Params...). The specified result is the value returned by doInBackground(Params...).

This method won't be invoked if the task was cancelled.

Parameters
result  The result of the operation computed by doInBackground(Params...)
```

perform the background task in doInBackground method and the task after the background task(displaying toast or dialog) in onPostExecute(String result) method.
The result returned from doInBackground(String...params)method will be received as parameter in onPostExecute(String result) method in result parameter.

To use this code segment, from your main activity call new DownloadFilesTask().excute(param1,param2,...,paramn).
This parameters will be received in doInBackground(String...params) in params.

```
Write in comment if you face any problem.
```

Happy coding!!!